# Trying to understand why simple angular 2 http.get() not working on localhost

Tags: cors, angular2-services

Trying to understand why such a simple rest call api not working from localhost (using angular-cli).

This is the **service code**:

```
commandsUrl ='http://www.mocky.io/v2/...';
  headers = new Headers({ 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' });
  options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers, withCredentials: true });

  getMyList (): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.commandsUrl, this.options)
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);

  }
  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body.data || { };
  }
  private handleError (error: Response | any) {
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
      const body = error.json() || '';
      const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
      errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
      errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
```

The error from browser is:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.mocky.io/v2/... Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Answer (score 0):

You have to read up on [CORS](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/). Before your real AJAX request is sent, the GET, an OPTIONS request is sent and the server must respond with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin' headers that give you permission to access it.

That is, the server at 'http://www.mocky.io/v2/...' has to be configured to accept CORS requests from your server (or using a wildcard)

https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: I have added header Access-Control-Allow-Origin to the response, but doesn't seems to change at all.

Comment: You added the header to the response of http://www.mocky.io/v2/? Do you have a URL I can call or a screenshot proving that the server is returning it? Your code is adding the header on request from the client, which doesn't do anything, the header must be sent as a response header.

Comment: Weird, it seems to work here. http://jsbin.com/qugaduqubo/1/edit?html,js,output but I don't see an OPTIONS request being made, which is the request that is probably not implemented

Comment: I am thinking maybe the problem is in angular-cli, something need to be configared maybe

Comment: I run an angular2 app that does CORS and I never had to configure anything. It's pretty weird. As a debugging option, I would try to run the XHR directly (without using angular as in the jsbin I linked to)

Comment: Can this be a proxy issue on the computer I'm using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136548/discussion-between-juan-mendes-and-angularone).